# Choosing a random enum in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, enums, typedef

I've created a typedef enum for my iPhone app...

```
typedef enum {
    FirstType,
    SecondType,
    ThirdType
} type;
```

Just for testing I'd like to be able to pick a random type from these.

I was going to use `arc4random() % 4` to do it and just use the int in its place but wanted to check if there was a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
typedef enum {
    FirstType = 0,
    SecondType,
    ThirdType,
    EnumTypeMax
} EnumType;

EnumType randomType = (EnumType) (arc4random() % (int) EnumTypeMax);
```

Note that `EnumTypeMax` is equal to `3`, not `4` and that is correct.
`EnumTypeMax` is considered to be an invalid value.

Also, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695787/669586) about an X-Macros solution.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Was just going to confirm that LastType never gets chosen but you've just confirmed that for me :D Plus tested and it works.  Thanks... Will accept when the timer runs out.

Comment: Renamed `LastType` to `EnumTypeMax`.

Comment: In iOS 4.3 and above you should use `arc4random_uniform(EnumTypeMax)` rather than `arc4random() % EnumTypeMax`